# Shell like scaling in Maya

Tags: maya

Is there a way to scale a duplicate of a mesh in Maya so that it acts like the shell instead of a proportional scale?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE 3d is barely on topic on this site. This is not about graphic design (graphic != graphics). But yes you can do this with a few tools like extrude and its  offset value then extract the face. You can also make it a curve and offset that.

Comment: I was able to achieve these results in Maya using offsets and extrudes before ... Unfortunately I am unable to recreate my past success.

It's strange that questions regarding 3D toolsets when designing graphics are off topic.  Is there a more relevant network on stackexchange for this sort of question?

Comment: No, one is under works, problem is that 3d is much harder than 2d. If illustrator generates 100 offset questions then 3d generates 1000000 offset questions. As such once you cross into 3D your assumed to be that much better and using extrude for this is as basic Maya operation as it gets. 3D question is fine if they aren't tech support questions like this how do i use my tools but clearly about the graphic design. This site would devolve very quickly. Check: that History is tuned on.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation Anyway one could use excel for graphic design but it wouldn't get many answers, and probably not on topic.

Comment: If this isn't the place for this sort of question I apologise. If you don't care to elaborate on the answer then please, feel free not to pipe in with useless condescension.